# Display data for all date ranges including missing dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursive-query

I'm having a issue with dates. I have a table with given from and to dates for an employee. For an evaluation, I'd like to display each date of the month with corresponding values from the second sql table.

SQL Table:

```
EmpNr | datefrom   | dateto     | hours
 0815 | 01.01.2019 | 03.01.2019 | 15
 0815 | 05.01.2019 | 15.01.2019 | 15
 0815 | 20.01.2019 | 31.12.9999 | 40
```

The given employee (0815) worked during 01.01.-15.01. 15 hours, and during 20.01.-31.01. 40 hours

I'd like to have the following result:

```
0815 | 01.01.2019 | 15
0815 | 02.01.2019 | 15
0815 | 03.01.2019 | 15
0815 | 04.01.2019 | NULL
0815 | 05.01.2019 | 15
...
0815 | 15.01.2019 | 15
0815 | 16.01.2019 | NULL
0815 | 17.01.2019 | NULL
0815 | 18.01.2019 | NULL
0815 | 19.01.2019 | NULL
0815 | 20.01.2019 | 40
0815 | 21.01.2019 | 40
...
0815 | 31.01.2019 | 40
```

as for the dates, we have:

```
declare @year int = 2019, @month int = 1;
WITH numbers
as
(
    Select 1 as value
    UNion ALL
    Select value + 1 from numbers
    where value + 1 <= Day(EOMONTH(datefromparts(@year,@month,1)))
)
SELECT b.empnr, b.hours, datefromparts(@year,@month,numbers.value) Datum FROM numbers left outer join 
emptbl b  on b.empnr = '0815' and  (datefromparts(@year,@month,numbers.value) >=  b.datefrom and datefromparts(@year,@month,numbers.value) <= case b.dateto )
```

which is working quite well, yet I have the odd issue, that this code is only shoes the dates between 01.01.2019 and 03.01.2019

thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Your numbers table is only produces numbers for January, which is why you are getting limited results.  Just modify it to produce results for all 2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check, if datefrom and dateto is in correct range?

Minimum value of DateTime field is 1753-01-01 and maximum value is 9999-12-31.

Look at your source table to check initial values.

Answer (score 1):

The recursive CTE needs to begin with `MIN(datefrom)` and `MAX(dateto)`:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (empnr INT, datefrom DATE, dateto DATE, hours INT);

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(815, '2019-01-01', '2019-01-03', 15),
(815, '2019-01-05', '2019-01-15', 15),
(815, '2019-01-20', '9999-01-01', 40),
-- another employee
(999, '2018-01-01', '2018-01-31', 15),
(999, '2018-03-01', '2018-03-31', 15),
(999, '2018-12-01', '9999-01-01', 40);

WITH rcte AS (
    SELECT empnr
         , MIN(datefrom) AS refdate
         , ISNULL(NULLIF(MAX(dateto), '9999-01-01'), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS maxdate -- clamp year 9999 to today
    FROM @t
    GROUP BY empnr

    UNION ALL

    SELECT empnr
         , DATEADD(DAY, 1, refdate)
         , maxdate
    FROM rcte
    WHERE refdate < maxdate
)
SELECT rcte.empnr
     , rcte.refdate
     , t.hours
FROM rcte
LEFT JOIN @t AS t ON rcte.empnr = t.empnr AND rcte.refdate BETWEEN t.datefrom AND t.dateto
ORDER BY rcte.empnr, rcte.refdate
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000) -- approx 3 years
```

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4ce70621d1a3d2460e759b45e8fad400)

Answer (score 0):

It could be in your select, try:

```
SELECT b.empnr, b.hours, datefromparts(@year,@month,numbers.value) Datum
FROM numbers 
LEFT OUTER JOIN emptbl b ON b.empnr = '0815' AND 
datefromparts(@year,@month,numbers.value) BETWEEN b.datefrom AND b.dateto
```

Comment: i'm still having the same issue, that only dates between the 01.01.2019 and 03.01.2019 are shown, the rest is filled with NULL - https://i.imgur.com/R5tB5TO.jpg

Comment: Can you run: SELECT DISTINCT empnr, hours, datefrom, dateto FROM emptbl WHERE datefrom >= '20190101' AND dateto <= '20191231' AND empnr = '0815'; It smells like there's nothing for that user outside of the dates you're seeing.

Comment: not quite. This is what the selection looks like. Currently Working on April: https://i.imgur.com/sURj5o3.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Your CTE produces only 31 number and therefore it is showing only January dates.

```
declare @year int = 2019, @month int = 1;

WITH numbers
as
(
    Select 1 as value
    UNion ALL
    Select value + 1 from numbers
    where value + 1 <= Day(EOMONTH(datefromparts(@year,@month,1)))
)
SELECT *
FROM numbers
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a24e58ef4ce522d3ec914f90907a0a9e

You can try below code,

```
with t0 (i)    as (select 0  union all  select 0  union all  select 0),
     t1 (i)    as (select a.i from t0 a ,t0 b ),
     t2 (i)    as (select a.i from t1 a ,t1 b ),
     t3 (srno) as (select row_number()over(order by a.i) from t2 a ,t2 b ),
     tbldt(dt) as (select dateadd(day,t3.srno-1,'01/01/2019') from t3)   
select  tbldt.dt 
from tbldt
where tbldt.dt <= b.dateto -- put your condition here
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b16469908b323b8d1b98d77dd09bab3d